# Android affiliate programme

Tags: google-play-store

I'm new to the Android world having lived in iOS for a long time. Does Google have an affiliate programme like the Apple store does with LinkShare?

If not, is there a reason why?

If not, is there one coming/rumoured?

Do site reviewing Android apps make no money on referrals at all?

Sorry for the multi-part question. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: We can't provide a good objective answer to the speculative parts, I suggest removing them.

Answer (score 2):

No there is no affiliate program for the Android Market.

Some individual apps that need to be side-loaded or have a seperate sign up for paid service offer affiliate programs but nothing through the official market.  Lots of people ask about it at the Google support threads but Google has not announced any plans to start an affiliate program nor have they commented on why they don't have one.

I don't believe anyone is earning money for referrals if they are sending people to the Official Market, Appbrain, Cryket, AndroLib or SlideMe.  If they are a commercial review site they are probably making money with display advertising, which incidentally improves the credibility of their reviews (because their income isn't dependent on you buying what they reviewed).